# Chrome Web Developer tools, live CSS editing won't work, resets to default

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Got strange Chrome Web Developer tools behavior. When I try to change existing CSS properties of element, after hitting enter, it's resets to previous default state. Earlier, all works well. Has disabled all extensions, nothing changes. What is this? 
p.s Chrome version 22.0.1229.94m

Comment: Try right clicking the element, *add attribute*, and set an inline style.

Comment: Inline styles works fine, but changing existing style won't, just resets. Why?

Comment: There's a bug that resets the styles (or doesn't apply them at all) when you set them in the *element style.* Maybe creating a new CSS class and applying it to the element might work.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any style that was set by my CSS file simply resets to the original value once I try to change it. I'm running Chrome 24.0.1290.1 dev. The **only** way to make style changes to the page in Chrome's Dev Tool is to create a new style property.

Comment: The problem OP describes can also occur if the styles you are trying to change are hardcoded/defined on the HTML element's `style` attribute i.e. `<p style="font-size: 17px;">` <-- you cannot change that in the side-bar that shows styles. To change it, you have to edit the HTML element.

Comment: I'm finding this on Kent C. Dodds blog in Chrome 99. I want to edit some CSS font and spacing (margin, padding) to make it easier to ead, but CANNOT :-( UGH! WHY??!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155795 has been fixed in the tip of tree, and the fix will eventually propagate into Chrome 23 (current beta) and Chrome 22 (current stable). Sorry about it, and thanks for your patience.

In any case, check your stylesheets for errors, since this kind of issues happens only while editing broken stylesheets. http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ is a good tool to use (pay attention to the "Parse error" errors.)

Comment: FYI, I came across this issue when @-viewport was written without the hyphen (@viewport). Interesting, given that the examples at [w3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#the-atviewport-rule) have it without the hyphen.

Comment: w3 validation stupid idea, I got `zoom:1` as an error, it doesn't exist, for chrome to make that decision is really poor.

Comment: It is definitely not the case that this only happens with broken stylesheets. This is STILL happening in 2015

Comment: @BT: Feel free to file a bug at http://crbug.com/new with all the specifics required to reproduce the issue (a reduced test case would be awesome). P.S. Are you by chance trying to edit a stylesheet injected into the page dynamically (i.e. through DOM operations)?

Comment: No, tho I would like to. I'm trying to use the element.style to work around that issue. Closing the tab and reopening the page solved the problem tho - corrupted tab? It happens intermittently, so I'm not sure how to pursue a repro (minimal or not).

Comment: That would be kind of expected if you had edited the stylesheet in the Sources tab inadvertently "breaking" it, but other than that I have no other clues as I'm no longer on the project.

Comment: Still happening in 2016. If, for example, I need to change the `left` of an element to `5%`, my workaround is to select that element, then on the console type `$0.style.left = '5%'` or using jQuery `$($0).css('left', '5%')`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but I found this failed to work when the AdBlock Plus extension was active..

This might be the bug, but I can't remember for sure.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138854&can=1&q=adblock%20cr%3DPlatform-DevTools&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified

I found that simply clicking the ABP icon and disabling it for the site in question restored functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome bug with @viewport was the cause for me: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278289

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check your stylesheet for errors - it may not even be anything that is obvious or that a CSS checker will find.

In my case the offending styles were some **input element pseudo-selectors**, for styling the placeholder text. Removed the lines, and it works perfectly again!

**Edit:**
The error in my case seems to be caused more specifically by placing *any of the non -webkit prefixed* input-placeholder pseudoselectors inside of a media query. Go figure...

Now on to figuring out why that's a problem...

Comment: Similar problem: Mine is breaking at this line: 
`@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {`
Works fine when I remove the `min-resolution` section of it.

Comment: Ahh, I was missing the "screen" part of the media query. This fixed it: 
`@media screen (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { `

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

Under Chrome Developer Tools > Settings > General Tab, check the option:

Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue on a site and I narrowed it down to a missing background resource.

I have switched to using FireFox for live CSS editing, never had a problem with the FireBug extension.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Chrome and try again...
You can also try reloading the page in a new tab.

It's probably a Chrome bug. It happens to me when I apply style to element with jQuery `css()` command, but I guess it can happen in many other scenarios as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I added a clarification.

Comment: Is there a solution for this bug as I am also adding css through jQuery CSS API and dev tool is not allowing to edit that css from the styles panel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. **After you make sure the file names are correct, removing the folder from the workspace, and adding it again** enabled live editing to work as usual again on chrome for local files.